# Fetching Data in a List

Tags: swiftui, fetch-api

I have a "news" section in my app. It display a list of news. It was perfectly working last week but for some reasons it's not working anymore and I can't figure out why. What I want is just a List of Items (news) and if the user click on it, it opens a NewsDetail View (which is not integrated in this question). Everything was ok, I tried to use print statements and I can see from console that I actually get data from API.
I'm new to iOS programming and I can't solve the issue.

I'll now show you my Model, where I setup my API call.

```
import Foundation
import Combine
import SwiftUI

class NewsModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var articles: [Article] = []
    @Published var filteredArticles: [Article] = []
    @Published var searchText: String = ""
    @Published var selectedArticle: Article?
    @State private var searchIsActive = false
    
    private var cancellables = Set<AnyCancellable>()
    
    func fetchDataFromAPI() {
let apiKey = "myApiKey"
let searchTerm = "riciclo"
let fromDate = "2023-11-03"
let language = "it"
let sortBy = "popularity"

if let url = URL(string: "https://newsapi.org/v2/everything?q=\(searchTerm)&from=\(fromDate)&sortBy=\(sortBy)&language=\(language)&apiKey=\(apiKey)") {
    URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher(for: url)
        .map(\.data)
        .decode(type: NewsResponse.self, decoder: JSONDecoder())
        .map(\.articles)
        .replaceError(with: [])
        .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
        .sink(receiveCompletion: { completion in
            switch completion {
            case .finished:
                print("Network request completed successfully")
            case .failure(let error):
                print("Network request failed with error: \(error)")
            }
        }, receiveValue: { [weak self] fetchedArticles in
            // Esegui il codice per estrarre e formattare la data qui
            let formattedArticles = fetchedArticles.map { article in
                var formattedArticle = article
                if let date = self?.formatDate(article.publishedAt) {
                    formattedArticle.publishedAt = date
                }
                return formattedArticle
            }
            self?.articles = formattedArticles
            print("Fetched Articles: \(formattedArticles)")
        })
        .store(in: &cancellables)
}
    
    func formatDate(_ dateString: String) -> String {
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'"
        dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "UTC")
        
        if let date = dateFormatter.date(from: dateString) {
            dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy/MM/dd"
            return dateFormatter.string(from: date)
        } else {
            return dateString
        }
    }
    
    func filterArticles() {
        if searchText.isEmpty {
            // Se la barra di ricerca è vuota, mostra tutti gli articoli
            Text("Nothing to display")
        } else {
            // Filtra gli articoli in base al testo immesso nella ricerca
            filteredArticles = articles.filter { article in
                return article.title.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased())
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is My View, where I setup my UI:

```
import SwiftUI

struct NewsListView: View {
    @StateObject var newsModel = NewsModel()
    @State private var selectedArticle: Article?
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color("whiteBackground").ignoresSafeArea()
            ScrollView {
                ForEach(newsModel.articles) { article in
                    VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 10) {
                        if let imageURL = article.urlToImage, let url = URL(string: imageURL) {
                            AsyncImage(url: url) { phase in
                                switch phase {
                                case .success(let image):
                                    image
                                        .resizable()
                                        .frame(width: 364, height: 183)
                                        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                                        .cornerRadius(6)
                                        .shadow(radius: 10)
                                default:
                                    ProgressView()
                                }
                            }
                            .onTapGesture {
                                selectedArticle = article
                            }
                        }
                        
                        Text(article.title)
                            .fontWeight(.semibold)
                            .foregroundStyle(Color.primary)
                            .lineLimit(2)
                            .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
                        
                        Text(article.description ?? "")
                            .fontWeight(.light)
                            .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
                            .lineLimit(3)
                            .foregroundStyle(Color.primary)
                        
                        HStack {
                            Image(systemName: "photo")
                                .resizable()
                                .clipShape(Circle())
                                .frame(width: 20, height: 20)
                                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                            
                            Text(article.source.name)
                                .fontWeight(.medium)
                                .foregroundStyle(Color.primary)
                            
                            Spacer()
                            
                            HStack {
                                Image(systemName: "clock")
                                    .foregroundColor(.gray)
                                
                                Text(article.publishedAt)
                                    .fontWeight(.thin)
                                    .foregroundStyle(Color.primary)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    .padding()
                }
            }
            .sheet(item: $selectedArticle) { article in
                NavigationView {
                    NewsDetailView(article: article)
                        .background(.ultraThinMaterial)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct Article: Identifiable, Decodable {
    var id = UUID()
    let source: Source
    let author: String?
    let title: String
    let description: String?
    let url: String
    let urlToImage: String?
    var publishedAt: String
    let content: String?
}

struct Source: Decodable {
    let id: String?
    let name: String
}

struct NewsResponse: Decodable {
    let status: String
    let totalResults: Int
    let articles: [Article]
}
```

And finally, the View where I want to show it all:

```
    import SwiftUI

struct NewsView: View {
    @State private var searchText = ""
    @StateObject var newsModel = NewsModel()
    @State private var isFirstTimeOpened = true
    
    var filteredArticles: [Article] {
        if searchText.isEmpty {
            return newsModel.articles
        } else {
            return newsModel.articles.filter { article in
                return article.title.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased())
            }
        }
    }
    
    init() {
    UIBarButtonItem.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf:[UISearchBar.self]).title = "Annulla"
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                if isFirstTimeOpened {
                    ProgressView()
                        .onAppear {
                            // Esegui la funzione solo se è la prima apertura dell'app
                            newsModel.fetchDataFromAPI()
                            isFirstTimeOpened = false
                        }
                } else {
                    NewsListView()
                }
            }
            .refreshable {
                newsModel.fetchDataFromAPI()
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("News", displayMode: .automatic)
            .searchable(text: $searchText, prompt: "Cerca") {
                ForEach(filteredArticles) { article in
                    Text(article.title)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

#Preview {
    NewsView()
}
```

I know it looks a mess, but for some reason it was working but now it's not anymore and I can't understand why. Any help?

Comment: At least there is a mistake in `NewsModel`: The methods `formatDate` and `filterArticles` are inside `fetchDataFromAPI` (they must on the top level of the class), so `self?.formatDate` will throw a compiler error. And `Text("Nothing to display")` makes no sense outside of a SwiftUI `view`.

Comment: Hi! I probably made a mistake while copying my code into StackOverflow, but in my code they're actually outside. I removed Text("Nothing to display") (idk why it was there lol) but it is still not showing any News at all. It doesn't even show "News" navigationTitle in my main view...

Comment: What is not working? What's the question?

Comment: I have a View in my App where I show a list of News. It was perfectly working for one week but now I can't understand why it it not working anymore

Comment: You say it was working, and now not working. What exactly working/not working?

Comment: If you check NewsListView you will see a List. I used it to show a list of news from my API, but for some reason it is not working anymore

Answer (score 0):

`NewsListView` has a separate model. You need to use the same instance you calling the fetch method in, e.g.:

```
struct NewsListView: View {
    @ObservedObject var newsModel: NewsModel
...
}

...

NewsListView(newsModel: newsModel)
```

Comment: It still doesn't work. I don't know what to test more..